Logs are showing in Docker Desktop but not in Grafana Dashboard
I am new to Loki and Grafana and right now I am trying to install Loki on a windows 2022 server. I am testing Grafana Loki in a Docker Compose setup, but not seeing any data ingested into Grafana dashboard. But I can see the logs in my Docker Dekstop.
Logs shown by Docker Desktop
Grafana Dashboard while Database is connected
Can anyone tell me where the problem might be?
I followed the installation from the Loki Documentation.
This is the Docker Compose Config:
version: "3"
networks:
  loki:
services:
  loki:
    image: grafana/loki:2.9.2
    volumes:
      - /home/pousy/loki/loki:/etc/loki
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/loki-config.yml
    networks:
      - loki
  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:2.9.2
    volumes:
      - /var/log:/var/log
      - /home/pousy/loki/promtail:/etc/promtail
    # ports:
    #   - "1514:1514" # this is only needed if you are going to send syslogs
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/promtail-config.yml
    networks:
      - loki
  grafana:
    environment:
      - GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING=/etc/grafana/provisioning
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE=Admin
    entrypoint:
      - sh
      - -euc
      - |
        mkdir -p /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources
        cat <<EOF > /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/ds.yaml
        apiVersion: 1
        datasources:
        - name: Loki
          type: loki
          access: proxy 
          orgId: 1
          url: http://loki:3100
          basicAuth: false
          isDefault: true
          version: 1
          editable: false
        EOF
        /run.sh
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    user: "1000"
    volumes:
    - /home/pousy/loki/grafana:/var/lib/grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - loki

the promtail-config file:
    server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: varlogs
      __path__: /var/log/*log

The loki config-file:
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 9096

common:
  instance_addr: 127.0.0.1
  path_prefix: /tmp/loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /tmp/loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /tmp/loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

query_range:
  results_cache:
    cache:
      embedded_cache:
        enabled: true
        max_size_mb: 100

ingester:
 wal:
  enable: true
schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: tsdb
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v13
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

ruler:
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093

# By default, Loki will send anonymous, but uniquely-identifiable usage and configuration
# analytics to Grafana Labs. These statistics are sent to https://stats.grafana.org/
#
# Statistics help us better understand how Loki is used, and they show us performance
# levels for most users. This helps us prioritize features and documentation.
# For more information on what's sent, look at
# https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/main/pkg/analytics/stats.go
# Refer to the buildReport method to see what goes into a report.
#
# If you would like to disable reporting, uncomment the following lines:
#analytics:
#  reporting_enabled: false

Grafana is successfully connecting to the data source “Loki” but usually it also adds the message that labels are found but in my case I only get a successful connection message, but no error message that can help me find out where the problem is.
here is the database URL setting:
database URL settings
I tried reinstalling the Docker Compose and the database but nothing changed. My only guess would be that there is an active filter in Grafana that is preventing me from seeing the logs or either the Host configurations are wrong
EDIT: I switched from a windows server to my home lab to test it first on a linux vm but I still have the same problem

Did you checked your Promtail/Loki container's logs?
